# is it safe to provide download link in www folder

Tags: php, mysql, apache

can I provide a download link in my www folder for the user to download?
can i send this link location(that expires in 7 days) in an email? I'm just concerned about the security

Comment: What does "security" mean here? If your server is secure a download link should be secure. If your server isn't, then it's not.

Comment: How does the link expire in 7 days?

Comment: am asking if providing a link to the files in www is safe or it can be used to hack into the directory and download all the files?

Answer (score 0):

No its not recommended.

Try this, make a function that takes the name of the file to download, put the logic in this function to get the file and set the header so that it can be download. By using this front end user do not know the exact path of file.

You can send that function url in email as well.

Comment: i am doing that @mayank but what is wanna know is that can i send the link in an email for the user to download later if he is unable to download the link directly after he makes a payment

Comment: what is this function url? how to generate it?

Comment: Its just like **www.yoursite.com/download.php?file=filename**

Comment: what would download.php look like?

Comment: Its a .php file having logic to download the filename